# CSS works fine in all Windows browser, but not in Firefox on OSX

Tags: css, windows, macos

I have some CSS and it works fine on Windows, but when I view it on OSX it's not quite right.

So that is the way it should look, wonderful :

[image]

And that is how Firefox 15 on OSX displays it :

[image]

The CSS:

```
nav#main ul>li.current {
height: 59px;
}

nav#main ul>li.current:before {
background: url('../img/top_shadow.png') no-repeat;
content: '';
display: block;
height: 7px;
margin: -7px 0 0 0;
}

nav#main ul>li.current:after {
background: url('../img/bottom_shadow.png') no-repeat;
content: '';
display: block;
height: 7px;
margin: 8px 0 0 0;
}

nav#main ul>li.current a {
background-color: #77b9de;
color: #3e3e3e;
height: 53px;
margin: -4px 3px -8px -3px;
padding: 3px 3px 0 10px;
}
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? I should point out as well, that if I move the background color to the `<li>` instead of the `<a>` it still does the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/eHhGa/

I added a quick version of it to a jsfiddle to see how the whole code looks.

Comment: The relevant information isn't the OS but the browsers (including the version if you're using IE).

Comment: Which browsers are you using?

Comment: Firefox, Chrome, IE and Opera all display fine on Windows. Firefox appears to be the only one on OSX that screws it.

Comment: What's the version of Firefox (on OSX) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, basically `overflow:hidden;` was taking effect on the container when the browsers height got below 500px and firefox was being strict about it.

Comment: It was stricter on OSX or did you have different window heights ? BTW, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: It wouldn't let me for two days, and yeah it was stricter on the OSX version for some reason. How odd.